# Naming a method, that setups up things, much like a ctor; Initialize is already taken

Tags: c#, naming

I have a simple naming problem. In my MVC code, I already have an initialize method that is provided by the framework. I'm thinking of another one that is called right before actions are executed.

It's basically like a second constructor, it setups essential data that is not available in the ctor. In fact, it's about data that is only available before an action executes.

Comment: ...which would mean a total of 3 constructor-like functions?  Maybe you need to split up your code into multiple classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You practically named it yourself: `PrepareForActions`.